# conflic by lock tfs, iisexpress applicationhost.config edited asp classic

Tags: tfs, asp-classic, iis-express, applicationhost

I have an old web site made in asp classic. I want to make it editable in VS2015 and using IISExpress. I use TFS as source controller.

I know how to make IISExpress work with the site. I need to change the applicationhost.config (myApp.vs\config\applicationhost.config)

For keeping those change for every developer, I added the applicationhost.config on TFS.

After that, I tested the solution on another computer. The local path of the solution is different than the first computer. When I load the solution, my project can't be loaded because IISExpress need to edit the applicationhost.config (changing the physicalPath of virtualDirectory).

At this point, the new computer user need to extract the applicationhost.config to be able to load the project. This will cause a new version of applicationhost.config if it's checked in, or an open file on the new computer.

So, my question is, is there a way that I did not need to extract the applicationhost.config? I want my solution ready to go on first get.

- I do not want to use IIS (local not express).
- I do not want forcing user to place the source on a specific folder on his computer.

---

**version 1 of the question (unclear)**

I have a website in asp classic.
I use VS2015 and IISExpress.

For working, I needed to change my applicationhost.config (.vs\config\applicationhost.config)

change required :

```
 <asp enableParentPaths="true" bufferingOn="true" errorsToNTLog="false" appAllowDebugging="false" appAllowClientDebug="false" scriptErrorSentToBrowser="false">
        <cache diskTemplateCacheDirectory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\ASP Compiled Templates" maxDiskTemplateCacheFiles="214748364" scriptEngineCacheMax="214748364" scriptFileCacheSize="429496729" />
        <limits bufferingLimit="2147483647" maxRequestEntityAllowed="2147483647" processorThreadMax="100" />
        <session allowSessionState="false" max="1000" timeout="00:20:00" />
      </asp>
```

I push on TFS. But now, If someone try to load my webProject, they got error because the project can't write applicationhost.config, and if he change it, everyone will have the new version. this problem is due of

```
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\pathToMySite" />
```

pointing to local folder (different depending on the user).

I search a way to keep my asp configuration on tfs and locked. I prefer to not force user to organize folder a requirement way.

I think those 2 configs cannot be in web.config

Comment: It would be helpful if you tightened your question to mention exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I rewrite the problem. hope its clearer.